# SVG filter taints canvas

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas

I've been trying to fight HTML5 Canvas anti-aliasing by filtering the canvas with this svg filter (from a stackoverflow-post):

```
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1;" >
  <defs>
     <filter id="remove-alpha" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" >
         <feComponentTransfer>
             <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"></feFuncA>
         </feComponentTransfer>
     </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

and then applying the filter to the canvas with

```
ctx.filter ='url(#remove-alpha)';
```

Everything works great, until I want to read from the canvas with [getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData). I've come to understand that the canvas gets [tainted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) from using an SVG. I wonder is there exists a workaround for me, so I can still use an "alpha-filter" without tainting the canvas.

Comment: I recognize my filter here ;-) There is no good reason obly this filter would taint the canvas since no crossOrigin reaources are implied here. If it is the case that would be a browser bug. C an't test rn but could you precise which browser and on which platform?

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the filter! :)

I'm on Chrome 68 with nothing but vanilla js. I'm on localhost atm, but the same problem appeared serving the files from a node.js-server. I do not experience the issue on Firefox v.61. 

"Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data."

Comment: then it's a Chrome bug. They've got no reason to taint it in this case, but I assume it's because they don't have the correct checks when the filter might indeed have some crossOrigin resources (e.g if there were an feImage) so they do taint always. As for a workaround... not so easy unfortunately. I guess it means you'd have to build this filter all with canvas API...

Comment: [Here is the ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=618871) that needs some update... feComponentTransfer is not on their white-list...

Comment: Ok  then I will have to try something else. Thanks a lot Kaiido! :)